# Consistency between type of the constraint List and the type of property

Tags: xml, validation, alfresco, jcr, ecm

I have a form in which I valorize the properties of a model.

When I create a property with the type `int`, and when I associate a constraint list with type `String` to this property, the form is submitted without any problem, 
but this causes an incoherence.

My question is: How to create a validator to ensure the consistency between type of the constraint list and the type of the property?

Comment: How do you get the properties of the model in order to build your form?

Comment: do you need the constraint list to be of type `String` or not? Otherwise, you could use the element: `minmax` which is a numeric value. Here: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/metadata-model-contraints.html